# Localtime until then format

Tags: java, java-time, duration, localtime

Wondering how to format output of a localtime with two different longs:
My goal here is to format the long minutes and long seconds with the until part

Example of desired output:
9:02
As in 9 minutes and 2 seconds

```
    public static String getTimeUntilSomething() {
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
        
        long minutes = currentTime.until(currentTimeMore, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        long seconds = currentTime.until(currentTimeMore, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

        String L = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("m:ss"));
        return L;
    }
```

Comment: added it, basicly im trying to figure out how to calculate times in bettween then formating it.

Comment: I don't understand what using the date format call is giving you. - why not just use `String.format()` to do this?  Is it that the `minutes` and `seconds` values don't trivially map to your output (ie: aren't necessarily `9` and `2` in your example)?

Comment: The String before was returning `return minutes % 60 + ":" + seconds % 60;` and String.format was retuning a null value, and i need to to display the 0 when the second is less than 10 as "09 secs left"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you say in your comment, I think you can just use `String.format()`, like this:

```
public static String getTimeUntilSomething() {
    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
    
    long minutes = currentTime.until(currentTimeMore, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    long seconds = currentTime.until(currentTimeMore, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    String L = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes % 60, seconds % 60);
    return L;
}
```

Comment: Changed this a little bit but i got it as i wanted, thank you

Comment: @fadjeca - This will return a wrong value. Try it for something like `LocalTime.of(21, 10, 20)` e.g. it's `19:38:27` in my timezone and this solution will give `31:53` which is wrong.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash - I know that. I was going by what the OP was asking for, which was just a formatting question.  I didn't try to change the "two longs" part of the problem...that seemed built into the question. - I think both answers have value.  I don't see my answer as wrong...and neither did the OP it seems.

Comment: @CryptoFool - You should correct it. The answer should be correct and complete.

Comment: I recommend against doing your own time math, as in your modulo operations. java.time can do all of your calculations for you, with a smaller risk of errors and clearer to read code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do it using [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getTimeUntilSomething(LocalTime.of(21, 10, 20)));
    }

    public static String getTimeUntilSomething(LocalTime currentTimeMore) {
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
        Duration duration = Duration.between(currentTime, currentTimeMore);

        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        return String.format("%2d:%02d", duration.toMinutes(), duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        // return String.format("%d:%02d", duration.toMinutes(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        // ####################################Java-9####################################
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
94:40
```